# Can somebody help me in understanding what is happening in this piece of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slice

I am not able to follow the set state method in this piece of code.

```
    locked: Array(5).fill(false), ///<<<  THIS IS THE INITIAL STATE

     this.setState(st => ({   //<<<<<  SETTING THE STATE ON BUTTON CLICK
      locked: [
        ...st.locked.slice(0, idx),
        !st.locked[idx], // << Iam not able to follow this line and the line after it.
        ...st.locked.slice(idx + 1)
      ]
```

Comment: Inverts the boolean at position `idx` in `locked`.

Comment: Would probably make more sense or be easier to read if it was written as `this.setState(st => ({ locked: st.locked.map((el, i) => i !== idx ? el : !el)}));` which simply toggles the boolean value in the array when the mapped index equals the specified index `idx`.

Comment: @Drew Reese Yes this was much easier to follow and understand.  This piece of code was very confusing and hard to understand in the course that iam taking. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locked` is an array of booleans. This code makes use of the spread syntax to create a new array of booleans from the current one but with one element at `idx` inverted. Detailed breakdown:

```
this.setState(st => ({              // callback version of setState that receives the current state as the argument
    locked: [                       // set a new array for `locked` that consists of :
        ...st.locked.slice(0, idx), // every element before the element at idx
        !st.locked[idx],            // the element at idx but inverted
        ...st.locked.slice(idx + 1) // every element after idx
    ]
```

You could also create a copy of the original array and invert the element at `idx` after that:

```
this.setState(st => {
    const locked = Array.from(st.locked);
    locked[idx] = !locked[idx];
    return {locked};
});
```

Or you could map over the array:

```
this.setState(st => ({
    locked: st.locked.map((item, i) => i === idx ? !item : item)
}));
```

All of those solve the problem of inverting the element at `idx` while creating a new array (react state must not be mutated).

Comment: OP is missing something about the code she/he's working on. There's no reason anyone would go to this trouble to return this as a new array with all this extra code unless there was a reason to compare its contents to the previously existing one.

Comment: @joshstrike How would you go about updating an array in a react state? You could of course also create a copy of that array and then invert the element at `idx`. But you have to create a new array for `locked` as react state shouldn't be mutated.

Comment: Same. I don't use React, but it's the same in any bound structure. What I'm pointing out is that the original code is definitely attempting to update a local copy of a view of a model, and compare it (probably for removal or limited update)... as opposed to just simple javascript to flip a boolean somewhere in an array. We're saying the same thing. This code is intended for comparison and possibly removing elements from the original.

Comment: @joshstrike This has to be done in order for react to update the components correctly. If you'd used react you would know that react state must not be mutated so you have to create a copy of `locked` one way or another. The way it's done in the question is very verbose but totally viable. There is nothing missing in order to answer the question. I don't see the point you are trying to make.

Comment: Got it. Sorry. Was trying to make a point without realizing that this was specific to React, I thought the OP was trying to understand someone's code and what I saw was a state that was about to be compared to another state, shallowly, and wanted them to be aware that there was a reason behind the spread syntax in the function.

Comment: @joshstrike I see. Yeah you could think that without knowing how react state works in detail. I generally try to get to the intention behind code too to avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/364724). But it that case it's just the fact that react requires you to create a shallow copy.

Comment: in this case it's a little unclear what the XY problem is because if you don't notice the reactjs tag on this post, it's entirely possible the poster doesn't know the syntax for `x=!x`. But yeah. From a broad view it's probably not the worst thing to note that there's gotta be a reason for someone to go to great lengths to create a shallow copy? Eh. SO. I never know what I'm about to step in ;) Pretty much every MVC has the same need for clarity to avoid race condition, they just put it in different places.

Answer (score 1):

It just negates the item at `idx` position.

How does it do it??

First it copies all the elements before `idx` from `locked` and pastes it back inside `locked` with below line.

```
this.setState(st => ({ 
   locked: [ ...st.locked.slice(0, idx)]
}));
```

And then it negates the item at `idx` position.

```
!st.locked[idx]
```

And then copies rest of the items back in array.

```
...st.locked.slice(idx + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//locked is a state property with an array value of 5 false booleans
locked: Array(5).fill(false)

//passing current state through a function
this.setState(st => ({ 
  //selecting locked property of state to update
  locked: [
    //making a copy of all indexes up to the index that is to be updated
    ...st.locked.slice(0, idx),
    //toggling the selected index to have a value of true (if previously false)
    !st.locked[idx], 
    //making a copy of all indexes after the index that is to be updated
    ...st.locked.slice(idx + 1)
    ]
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make complete sense without understanding where `idx` is coming from. But it takes everything in the `st.locked` array and leaves it the same, except for `idx`, which it inverts.

Then it returns a *new array* with those elements, which must have been done intentionally. Otherwise it would be much more trivial to target st.locked[idx]. *There is some reason the author of this code is returning a new array* and it's probably important.

Comment: It's an array in react state, you have to return an ***entirely new*** array reference anyway, which *always* requires shallowly copying the existing array, otherwise it's considered a state mutation and that is no good.

Comment: Ah. Okay - I was thinking of this as "why is this dude facing a problem not just mutating an array" and didn't realize that (a) it's React  --not my scene-- and (b) React doesn't want you to do that because it isn't actually two-way watching object mutations and diffing them, it must be polling or just taking the later input from the backend, or something. Whatever, I roll my own, and that's a good reason not to use it. I just recognized this pattern as something that shouldn't be messed with without understanding that it's intentionally creating a second shallow copy.

Comment: Leaving this answer here because it's not wrong, just an insight from someone who doesn't use React but would read this as plain JS in a large project base.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I Tried This On This piece of code and now  I am clear about it.

```
    const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];
    console.log(animals.slice(0, 2));
    console.log(animals[2] = "New Item Bro")
    console.log(animals.slice(2  + 1));
    console.log(animals)
```